# How to display the 404 error page instead bugs in Symfony4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

this my page : error404.html.twig as documentation [Example 404 Error Template](https://symfony.com/doc/master/controller/error_pages.html#use-default-exception-controller)

```
{# templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig #} 
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Page not found</h1>
        <p>
            The requested page couldn't be located. Checkout for any URL
            misspelling or <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">return to the homepage</a>.
        </p>

{% endblock %}
```

**this my page config/routes/dev/twig.yaml**

```
# config/routes/dev/twig.yaml
_errors:
    resource: '@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
    prefix:   /_error
```

**this my page config/packages/twig.yaml**

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    exception_controller: App\Controller\ExceptionController::showException
```

**what i should do to make it works?**

- **by the way i used the first methode** : *override the default error templates.*

**the erreur is :** :
[image]

**services.yaml :**
[image]

Comment: Did you test to go to http://localhost/index.php/_error/404?

Comment: So what's the problem? In what way does this not work as you expect it to?

Comment: yes i did localhost/index.php/_error/404? it redirect me to xampp dashboard

Comment: where is your showException method in the ExceptionController  class that you customize  ?

Comment: i didnt make any controller in the documentation they override it else what i should do exactly ?

Comment: Please share more details by editing your question - what's the exact problem, and what have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're in debug mode and instead of a 404 page you get a `NotFoundHttpException` then everything is fine in that this is the documented and desired behaviour, as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

> In the development environment, Symfony catches all the exceptions and displays a special exception page

To bypass this and actually see your custom 404 page you need to access the template via a special route: `http://localhost/index.php/_error/404`

Comment: Actually it's when you're in debug mode, irrespective of the environment.